# Unable to redirect user login based on Roles

Tags: vba, redirect, authentication

I'm having some difficulty getting my login to redirect users based on their roles. When I login either a user/admin, they get redirected to the Default.aspx instead of the specified pages. I've been looking at this code too much and can't see anything wrong with it. Any ideas on why I'm having this problem would be extremely appreciated.

This is my Login.aspx

```
    If you have don't have an account, <a href="CreateUser.aspx">Create one here!</a><br />
    <br />
&nbsp;<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DisplayRememberMe="true">
    </asp:Login>
```

This is my Login.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Security

Partial Class ContentPages_Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub page_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            If Me.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
                Response.Redirect("~/ContentPages/Login.aspx")
            Else
                Session.Abandon()
                Session.Clear()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
    Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login1.Authenticate
        FormsAuthentication.Initialize()

        Dim USER_ID As Integer = 0
        Dim roles As String = String.Empty
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Validate_User")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_NAME", Login1.UserName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", Login1.Password)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            reader.Read()
            USER_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader("USER_ID"))
            roles = reader("Roles").ToString()
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Select Case USER_ID
            Case -1
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
            Case -2
                Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated."
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                Dim ticket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), Login1.RememberMeSet, roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
                Dim hash As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
                Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash)

                If ticket.IsPersistent Then
                    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration
                End If
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
                Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet))

                If Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso User.IsInRole("Admin") = True Then
                    Response.Redirect("~/AdminPages/CustomerList.aspx")
                ElseIf Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso User.IsInRole("User") = True Then
                    Response.Redirect("~/ClientPages/CustomerProfile.aspx")
                End If

                Exit Select
        End Select

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the correct location path ="~/foldername" in the webconfig. Now works as intended